# I want to add string array to this function to filter displayed option in drpodown

Tags: filters

Wordpress wpallimport plugin This filter allows modifying the option shown in the options type dropdown for import

The function is as follow: I want to add $custom_types as string array.

```
function wpai_custom_types( $custom_types ) {   

   // Modify the custom types to be shown on Step 1.
    $custom_types = array("woocommerce orders" , " posts")
   // Return the updated list. 
   return $custom_types;

}
add_filter( 'pmxi_custom_types', 'wpai_custom_types', 10, 1 );
```

But it won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posts & products:

```
add_filter( 'pmxi_custom_types', 'example_import_show_only_posts_and_products', 10, 2 );

function example_import_show_only_posts_and_products ($custom_types, $type = '') {
    
    global $wpdb;
    
    $new_types = array();
    
    foreach ($custom_types as $post_key => $post_obj) {
        if ( $post_key == 'post' || $post_key == 'product' ) {
            $new_types[$post_key] = $post_obj;
        }
    }
    
    return $new_types;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce Orders are registered as `shop_order` not "woocommerce orders".  Also you have a space in " posts".

Try:

```
$custom_types = array("shop_order" , "post");
```

Posts aren't custom post types in WordPress though.  They're of the default post types that are registered in WP.

Comment: i tried this and it didn't work but i contacted the support and they provided another function